# How to replace my old html with new html via jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my codes and I want to replace id url with a js function with a click. How can i do it?

for example: I want to replace '11111','url-content' and 'height' and 'width' with my js function.

```
<div id="divMedia">
        <a style="display: block; width:600px; height:400px;" id='11111'>
        </a>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            flowplayer('11111', 'flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', {

                onLoad: function () {
                    this.setVolume(30);
                },
                playlist: [
                    {
                        url: 'http://localhost:3080/PlayList/icon_survey.gif',
                        scaling: 'orig'
                    },
                    {
                        autoPlay: false,
                        autoBuffering: true,
                        url: 'http://localhost:3080/PlayList/renren.flv'
                    }
                ],
                onMouseOver: function () {
                    this.play();
                },
                onMouseOut: function () {
                    this.stop();
                }
            });</script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is that content static when the page loads?  The content besides what you want to change out, I mean.

Comment: Hi Calvin, what i want to change is 11111, http://localhost:3080/PlayList/icon_survey.gif, and 600px ,400px...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this javascript function:

```
function changeLink(){
    document.getElementById("11111").innerHTML = "newURLContent";
    document.getElementById("11111").style.width = "newWidth";
    document.getElementById("11111").style.height = "newHeight";
    document.getElementById("11111").id = "newID";
}
```

... with this html for the link ...

```
<a style="display: block; width:600px; height:400px;" onclick="changeLink()" id='11111'>
</a>
```

I wasn't sure exactly what you meant by "url-content" but hopefully this works.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Hi Jebego, what i mean is i want to update all these html in div... in another js function, and url -content is something like 'http://localhost:3080/PlayList/icon_survey.gif', i saw your answer but it looks like to update by element Id.. how can I update html directly?

Comment: are you sure that you know what you want? Maybe you cannot express well that, but updating the inner HTML and style of an element is by all way 'direct'.

Comment: Well, to change HTML with JavaScript, you need to be able to assign what element you are changing. You can do this with getElementById, the most common method, or you can getElementByName, or by TagName. I'm still not 100% sure what you are attempting to do, as Marino posted, updating innerHTML is about as direct as you can get. Could you explain a bit more what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Actually I might get what you are saying about editing the url-content. The 'http://localhost:3080/PlayList/icon_survey.gif' that you are attempting to change however is part of a javascript function, and I do not think you can change the HTML that rendered it with another javascript function. You will have to modify the function its self so that when the link is clicked it poits to a new url. Maybe you can have a variable that changes when a user clicks on the link, and you check to see if the variable has changed before setting the url.

Comment: Hi Marino & Jebego, sorry i didn't express clearly... What i want is update javascript HTML via another js function, and now I think i know how to update it, i will update itself to change its parameters..